# What happens if you relax the "for all" requirement of Darboux integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Here's the definition of Darboux integration that I'm working with:

> A bounded function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is D-integrable iff $\forall \, \epsilon >0, \exists \, \delta
> > 0$ such that for every partion $P$ with $||P|| < \delta$ we have $U(P,f) -L(P,f) < \epsilon$

Why do I need **every** partition to have norm less than $\delta$. Doesn't exhibiting **at least** one partition do the job? What would go wrong here?

This question is inspired from another definition of D-integration:

> A bounded function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is D-integrable iff for every $\epsilon >0$, there exits a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ such
> that $U(P_{\epsilon},f) - L(P_{\epsilon},f)< \epsilon$

This definition seems to require that exhibiting at least one partition that satisfies the condition is enough.

**Question:** Could this have something to do with boundedness for the first definition? For instance, in the first definition if we remove the "function is bounded" requirement, would the definition still be true? You know, just like in the definition of Riemann integration where we don't mention the function is bounded.

---

For reference: the Riemann integration definition:

A function (bounded or not, we don't mention) $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is R-integrable with integral $I$ iff $\forall \, \epsilon>0, \exists \, \delta >0$ such that for every tagged partion $P^T$ with norm less than $\delta$, we have the $|\sum f(t_i)(x_i - x_{i-1}) - I|< \epsilon$

Comment: Reminder— my question is actually about relaxing the boundedness condition on the first definition OR If you keep the boundedness, can you drop the $\forall$ from it? I know the two definitions are equivalent so I'm not looking for proofs of their "equivalency".

Comment: What do you mean by dropping the universal quantifier? Do you mean to replace it with an existential quantifier over $\epsilon$?

Comment: (Atleast one of) $U(P,f)$ or $L(P,f)$ will not even make sense if your function is unbounded. So, if you drop boundedness from the precondition, you can't make sense of the resulting statement, which is in contrast with the definition for Riemann integration, which doesn't use supremum/infimum in its definition anywhere, just pointwise values of the function $f$, so there it makes sense to drop boundedness as a precondition.

Comment: ^ oh and if you admit that $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$ make sense (in $\Bbb{R}$) for some partition $P$, then $f$ is automatically bounded on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Amazing catch! I completely forgot about that. Guess then that means the question remains about relaxing "$\forall$" from the first definition.

Comment: @masiewpao I've already explained that in the question body. Let me know if it needs more improvement although I don't think I can add any more details.

Comment: of course you can relax it. If $\forall P$ is replaced by $\exists P$ in definition 1, that clearly implies definition 2. Definition 2 implies Riemann integrability, which implies the original definition 1, which clearly implies the modified definition 1. There may be a more direct way of arguing this, but since you say you know the equivalences, this is an easy way to justify things.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Okay let's do this a little more slowly. If I relax the $\forall$ in the $1$. I get, $\exists\delta$ such that for some ($\exists$) partition $P$ with $||P||< \delta$ which is really the same as saying $\exists P_{\epsilon}$ and then set $\delta = ||P_{\epsilon}|| +1$ hence $1 \implies 2$. And I suppose, I can show that $2 \implies 1$ by setting $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2K(n-1)}$ and defining common refinement $R = P \cup P_{\epsilon}$ where $P$ is **any** partion with norm $<\delta$ and $|f(x)|≤K$ and using the "$R$ has $n-1$ points more than $P$ argument. So $2 \implies 1$

Comment: But then what is really the use of definition 1? Why even mention it as a seperate definition? It just looks like a lot more extra work than what is necessary...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137545/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-william).

Comment: Your second definition is actually "for all partitions $P$ finer than $P_{\epsilon} $ we have $U(P, f) - L(P, f) <\epsilon $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Really? How? I don't think so because "there exists a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ that does the job" doesn't imply that all partitions finer than $P$ also do the job. There may be a partition finer than $P_{\epsilon}$ that doesn't for work for the said $\epsilon$. It's a slightly more "relaxed" version if you ask me. And going to "every partition finer than $P_{\epsilon}$" doesn't "logically" follow, it would require some work like taking a common refinement and stuff.

Comment: If $P_{\epsilon} $ works then any partition finer than it also works. Rmemeber that $P$ is said to be finer than $P'$ if $P'\subseteq P$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Oh my bad, I thought you were using the word "finer" in English sense, to mean $||P'|| ≤ ||P||$. Now, in which case, I would like to understand what was the point you were trying to make with that comment? I don't get it. All partitions finer than $P_{\epsilon}$ do the job, yes but how does that information help? :(